# unable to access .env files while running with uwsgi

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, wsgi, dotenv

I'm using smtplib to send simple emails for booking in a flask application I'm using google mail and have an app password as well as allowed less secure applications.  I have the booking system running on my personal computer, but as soon as I port it over to the VPS it stops working, for an unknown reason other than the username and password are not accepted, but they are definitely correct, and it will run by itself but wont when run in wsgi and nginx.

Nginx config

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    # return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:/path/too/chatbot.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name example.com;`

ssl_certificate /path/too/keys.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/too//primarykey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /path/too//keys.pem;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions

# curl https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ffdhe2048.txt > /path/to/dhparam
#ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam;

# intermediate configuration
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

# replace with the IP address of your resolver
resolver 8.8.8.8;
location /  {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/path/too/chatbot.sock;
}

}
```

UWSGI.ini file

```
[uwsgi]

module=wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5
enable-threads = true



socket = chatbot.sock
chmod.socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

.env

```
DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID=projectid
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=Ajsonfile.json
RESTFUL_CREDENTIALS=restful_credentials.json
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apasswordforemailaddress
```

My current thinking is that wsgi or nginx are unable too find the file due to some sort of permissions issue but I've chown'ed all the related files, I'm getting the same issue with my google api key now too.

all the information is stored in a .env file which has the correct group access, along with all the other files running on the site already.

I don't know what would be helpful to post here other than I'm using nginx and wsgi to expose a flask application, some items are stored in a .env file that doesn't seem to be read.

Comment: Something is broken. I'm not sure what else we're expected to say if you don't give a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

To get them to load while running in WSGI you need to use dot-env package

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
```

Answer (score 0):

`[uwsgi]`

`base = /var/www/html/poopbuddy-api`

`chdir = %(base)`

`app = app`

I don't know exactly what `chdir` does but I think it at least sets the default location to the root directory of the app.  From there, load_dotenv() works.